# Using DAC to control supply voltage of bus transciever?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, dac

I am designing simple logic analyzer with SN74LVC16T245DGGR bus transceiver which could be used for 1.2V to 5V logic levels I would like to control supply voltage of input port with DAC, currently TLV5624, but this DAC could deliver only 1mA current and I doubt that it's enough for transceiver so I put LM321 OPAMP but this OPAMP has 1.5V voltage drop so with 5V supply I can get only to 3.5V which doesn't enable me to interface 5V logic.

Is there any single supply OPAMP with lower voltage drop? I would need to get to at least 4.5V. And using some charge pump to get higher supply voltage is not the way for me, because it should be USB powered and I don't want to have high power consumption.

Or would it be better to control feedback of some buck voltage regulator with DAC? It seemed to me as overkill to use voltage regulator for this with all inductors and capacitors and I think that these regulators have high voltage drop as well.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you want to generate the supply of the logic circuit? You're going to need ground from the target circuit anyway,  why not also pull in logic supply?

Comment: That might be valid point, but I didn't want to resort on supply of target device and I wanted to use it as signal generator also, that's why I chose generating my own supply.

Comment: Fair enough. You should be aware of how you're dealing with referencing the signals, though. It's generally not a good idea to use logic signals generated by one power supply to interface with another, especially when they are separate supplies entirely. If the target is powered off but your device is on, you risk turning on the target through the IO lines your device is connected to, which can cause unwanted behavior and also damage over the long term.

Comment: This is after all good idea, I might be as well add some jumper that would make me able to chose from internal or external supply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a *rail to rail* opamp. These are opamps like any other, but are designed to allow the outputs to get very close to the supply rails. I'd give you examples, but there are *thousands*. Whatever electronics distributor you prefer should have an entire category for them.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed, do you know some pin compatible drop-in replacements for LM321 and LM324? Or where I could find some?

Comment: It's probably worth adding the caution that most rail-to-rail op-amps lose drive capability when the output is near the rail.

Comment: @BrunoKremel just searching op-amps for ["rail to rail" at mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Amplifier-ICs/Operational-Amplifiers-Op-Amps/_/N-6j73m?Keyword=rail+to+rail) turns up 6229 results. Most op-amps have the same pin configuration, so should be compatible with LM321.

Comment: Thank you guys, I found some on farnell I will look into specs to see wether it could power that transceiver.

Comment: Have you considered using an LM317 adjustable voltage regulator, with a digital pot to set the output voltage?

Comment: @ScottSeidman LM317 is probably not a good choice since OP said he had an issue with dropout voltage. But there are other adjustable regulators that are controlled the same way that need much less overhead Vin to Vout.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I thought that voltage regulators has too much of voltage drop and I would not be able to get to 4.5V margin out of 5V... and since that transceiver do not have high consumption I decided for DAC buffered with OPAMP.

Comment: Valid point about the LDO, but using an op amp doesn't quite feel right either. @ThePhoton points out that there may be adjustable LDO regs.  I'd go w/ one of them, after verifying current flow through adjustment resistors doesn't exceed spec on dig. pots.

Comment: Traditional linear regulators like LM317 needed something like 1 or 1.2 V headroom (drop-out voltage). Newer parts, called low-drop-out (LDO) regulators can require as little as 0.2-0.3 V overhead. So with 5 V supply, you could get as high as 4.7 V output. But there are nearly as many of these parts to choose from as there are rail-to-rail op-amps. TI is one place to start looking for a LDO that matches your needs.

Comment: TPS77001, for example, is adjustable and supplies up to 50 mA with an advertised 0.035 V drop-out (I haven't tried the part myself). The other thing to check is how much power your regulator will burn when the output voltage is at minimum, but this will also be an issue for an op-amp solution, and the regulator package is more likely to be optimized for thermal dissipation.

Comment: Problem might be that for this and other LDO regulators I have seen they recommend using resistors in range of 100 to 500 Ohm and I have seen only 1kOhm and more digital pots.. but 1kOhm would be probably still usable with less precision which is not that crucial for me..

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with something like this with possibility to bypass internal logic supply.. Using LDO regulator from TI and digital pot: [image]